# Use Ruby variable when calling exec powershell.exe in script

Tags: ruby, powershell

Writing some ruby code, some of which will be making Powershell calls using the exec powershell.exe command.

How do I use an existing Ruby variable and pass it to the Powershell command?

Code:

```
mydata = 12345
exec 'Powershell.exe write-host #{mydata}'
```

That doesn't work.  How do I use the mydata Ruby variable in the powershell call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to interpolate a value in a string, you need to use double quote.

```
exec "Powershell.exe write-host #{mydata}"
```

instead of

```
exec 'Powershell.exe write-host #{mydata}'
```